# Three.js STL-model transparency: disappearing of parts of the model

Tags: javascript, three.js

Good morning,

we have found a strange behaviour using Three.js to show a STL-model.
Trying to enable transparency causes some parts of the 3D-model to disappear, when they are hidden by another transparent part.
Other parts behind be the very same transparent part can be seen.

Since I'm new to stackoverflow I'm not allowed to add a picture, but two screenshots showing the behaviour I described can be found on github, where I reported this issue first:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7929

Screenshot 1 shows the outside parts of the model, screenshot 2 shows that most of them disappear when hidden by a transparent part.

Transparency itself obviously works, but some parts somehow just disappear.
Our loader is based on the provided STL-loader but with some extensions regarding coloring.

Any suggestions on what could be wrong / what we are doing wrong or is this an issue with three.js itself?

Thank you for all your feedback and sorry for probably not sticking to all conventions here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Read about transparency and three.js on this site. Also transparency and WebGL. A work-around is to set `transparent: false` in your materials.

Answer (score 1):

When you load your stl model, try to set material doubleside:

```
material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

maybe this will solve the problem.